# PopupWindow covers Navigation bar in Android 5.1

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I am showing the popupWindow in my app showing it using

> popupWinow.showAsDropDown(anchor)

It works fine on pre lollipop devices but on android 5 and 5.1 it covers the navigation bar. Tried using `setAttachedInDecor` but no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using showAtLocation for 5.1.